# Genealogy tree with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, fontsize

I am trying to use [this document](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1z8hEXx9jqFif9EnaywGaE3MrSsHkMeD3TbK4A38C2YwoewheonEk71_k) to produce a genealogy tree.

At page 261, it refers to a freely scalable text font. And do not have a clue what this means. I searched the Internet for that but didn't find any helpful answers. So far I only found predefined sizes with `\Huge`, or `\tiny` style of command, or by defining a new command at the preamble with `\newcommand` with instructions to set a special font size. But here I need something that is freely scalable, as in a size I can change whenever I want to whichever size I need as I am writing the document. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I think you refer to section 6.2.1 on page 123. It says that `processing=fit` options needs a font which can be adapted to needed size. If you look at examples in page 125, you'll see that all nodes keep a similar size but font i automatically adjusted to fit the text.